# How to initialize a unsigned char array?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

What I am really trying to achieve is an array of dynamic byte patterns that I can use as a pattern searcher when I buffer binary files. But I am starting off basic for now. I have the following code that I based off of an example found on StackOverflow.

[How to Initialize a Multidimensional Char Array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845089/how-to-initialize-a-multidimensional-char-array-in-c)

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;

int main()
{
    BYTE *p[2][4] = {
        {0x44,0x58,0x54,0x31},
        {0x44,0x58,0x54,0x00}
    };

    return 0;
}
```

I compile it with mingw32 for Windows.

```
D:\> gcc example.c -o example.exe
```

I get the following warnings when I try to compile.

```
example.c: In function 'main':
example.c:6:3: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
example.c:6:3: warning: (near initialization for 'p[0][0]') [enabled by default]
example.c:6:3: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
example.c:6:3: warning: (near initialization for 'p[0][1]') [enabled by default]
example.c:6:3: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
example.c:6:3: warning: (near initialization for 'p[0][2]') [enabled by default]
example.c:6:3: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
example.c:6:3: warning: (near initialization for 'p[0][3]') [enabled by default]
example.c:7:3: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
example.c:7:3: warning: (near initialization for 'p[1][0]') [enabled by default]
example.c:7:3: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
example.c:7:3: warning: (near initialization for 'p[1][1]') [enabled by default]
example.c:7:3: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
example.c:7:3: warning: (near initialization for 'p[1][2]') [enabled by default]
```

I don't understand the nature of this warning. How do I go about resolving it? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Drop the `*` from `BYTE *p[2][4]`:

```
BYTE p[2][4] = {
    {0x44,0x58,0x54,0x31},
    {0x44,0x58,0x54,0x00}
};
```

You want a multidimensional array of `char`: `BYTE p[2][4]` not a multidimensional array of `pointer-to-char`.

Comment: Wow. That was such an easy fix. I'm curious. Why do you drop the pointer when the example I linked used a pointer for something that looks very similar to what I am looking for?

Comment: @redsolar In that code the inner-most element is itself an array (`"00"`).

Comment: Oh. I see now. Thank you for clearing that up and thank you for your answer. Much appreciated.